# PostGIS Nearest Neighbor query performance - can it be quicker?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, postgis-2.0, proximity

I want to canvas the community to see if my nearest neighbor query can be optimized at all.  I am happy with my current results, but I'm always up for improving.  I have 2 tables, lakes and towns.  I want to get the nearest town to each lake within 0.5 degrees.  I use a calculation to get a cardinal direction output as an integer (ceil function).  Below is the query.  Any other suggestions are also welcome.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (lakes.wkb_geometry) lakes.wkb_geometry, lakes.ogc_fid AS lakes_id, lakes.name AS lakes_name, 
towns.ogc_fid AS towns_id, upper(towns.name) AS towns_name,
ceil(degrees(ST_Azimuth(lakes.wkb_geometry, towns.wkb_geometry))/90) AS card_dir
FROM lakes, towns
WHERE ST_DWithin(lakes.wkb_geometry, towns.wkb_geometry, 0.5)
ORDER BY lakes.wkb_geometry, ST_Distance(lakes.wkb_geometry, towns.wkb_geometry);
```

Comment: To get help about postgres performance better to show the EXPLAIN of the query.

Comment: These may be interesting reading even they do not solve your use case http://boundlessgeo.com/2011/09/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/ and http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/geometry_distance_knn.html

Comment: From the same source as user30184, but going into more detail: http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/knn.html

Comment: Maybe apply the "distinct on" clause to the `fid` rather than the geometry. Looks pretty straightforward to me otherwise.